# Java Function andThen signature explained

Tags: java

The [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) of andThen is: `(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)`

I cannot understand why the input of the function is : *? super R*

In my understanding, super is used when we are writing a value. But the function passed to andThen will read the value of first function.

For ex:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = x -> x * 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = x -> x * 3;
Integer myApplyThen = (input) -> {
    Integer y1 = f1.apply(input);
    Integer y2 = f2.apply(y1);
    return y2;
}
```

As we can see in this logic that there is no need to write any value to the generic parameters passed to Function. Both `f1.apply` and `f2.apply` are just transforming their inputs i.e reading and returning.
So according to me, the type definition of *andThen* should have been: `Function<? extends R,? extends V> after`

But since this is not the case, what am I missing?

Comment: A `Function` _consumes_ an argument and then _produces_ a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason isn’t obvious when you use Integer, which is a final class and therefore cannot have a subclass.

Consider this:

```
Function<Number, Number> f1 = x -> x.doubleValue() * 2;
Function<Double, Double> f2 = x -> x.doubleValue() * 3;

Number myApplyThen = (input) -> {
    Number y1 = f1.apply(input);
    Double y2 = f2.apply(y1);    // ERROR: f2 requires a Double!
};
```

The function given to andThen needs to be capable of handling the result type, R.  If it accepts a supertype, then we know it can handle R as input;  for example, a `Function<Object, String>` will accept any value as input.

But if the function given to andThen only accepts a *subset* of R, which is what `? extends R` (potentially) signifies, then it is not safe to assume you can pass any R instance to it.

We can see this in the above example:  f2 expects a particular subtype of Number as input, and since the compiler only knows that f1 is capable of returning a Number object, which might be a Double or Integer or BigDecimal or AtomicLong, it is not safe to pass that result as input to f2.